# How does AppDynamics APM works internally?

Tags: appdynamics, apm

How does AppDynamics works internally, In my current company we are planning to use AppDynamics but teams want to know how it actually works such as How it collects data, how does it communicate and how it intercepts java transactions and other related stuff.

So I tried looking into AppDynamics knowledge base but did not get accurate technical answer I need.

Answer (score 0):

Due to its proprietary nature i don't think the internals are available for anyone to view or discuss.

Below link might give an idea of how the product works at a high level.

https://www.appdynamics.com/product/how-it-works/

Comment: Thanks for sharing @rdev1991, To understand how APM works I looked into some other APM software and found that the usually use Java Bytecode Instrumentation technology. Below are some references I have gone through.

https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/pohjalai/k05/okk/seminar/Aarniala-instrumenting.pdf
https://technoga.wordpress.com/2012/12/01/what-is-bytecode-instrumentation/